# $x \to e^{ix}$ , $[0,2\pi[$ onto $S_1$ is no a homeomorphisms

Tags: general-topology

$f: x \to e^{ix}$ , $[0,2\pi[$ onto $S_1$, is no a homeomorphsims.

Idea: We know $e^{ix} \leftrightarrow (\cos x,\sin x)$ onto $S_1 \subset \mathbb{R}^2$. Must be find a contraexample such that $f^{-1}$ or $f$ lest continuous.

Answer (score 2):

The idea is the following : if $x_{0} \in ]0,2\pi[$, then $[0,2\pi[ \smallsetminus \lbrace x_{0} \rbrace$ is not connex. However, $\mathbb{S}^{1} \smallsetminus \lbrace e^{ix_{0}} \rbrace$ is connex (because it is pathwise-connected). If $x \in [0,2\pi[ \, \longmapsto \; \mathbb{S}^{1}$ was a homeomorphism, $[0,2\pi[ \smallsetminus \lbrace x_{0} \rbrace$ would be connex.